# How to add click to specific item in listView

Tags: java, android, listview, mobile, adapter

I did ListView with some items, now I want when I click on specific item to send me to 'next' activity.

I write this code:

```
  listViewProduct.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> list, View v, int pos, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(DrugaStranica.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });
```

But it is work for all item some, I want specific item to send me to specific activity.

Comment: What is your decision parameter?

Comment: Just put your code inside a `if(condition)`.

Comment: @XcombeX Can you please check code It may be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below code it may be helpful to solve your issue.

```
listViewProduct.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> list, View v, int pos, long id) {
                Intent intent;
                switch (pos) {
                    case 0:
                        intent = new Intent(DrugaStranica.this, TestOneActivity.class);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        intent = new Intent(DrugaStranica.this, TestTwoActivity.class);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        intent = new Intent(DrugaStranica.this, TestThreeActivity.class);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        intent = new Intent(DrugaStranica.this, TestFourActivity.class);
                        break;
                    default:
                        intent = new Intent(DrugaStranica.this, MainActivity.class);
                        break;
                }

                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });
```